# ¿Cómo fijar la altura dependiendo del contenido de un GridView en Android dentro de un ScrollView?

Tags: java, android

En Android cuando pones objetos dentro del `ScrollView` me encuentro que `height="wrap_content"` no se comporta de tal manera, solo muestra la altura lo que ocupa un ítem.

Código que tengo actualmente `content_main`

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scroll_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnWidth="120dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

¿Hay otra forma de ajustar automáticamente la altura dependiendo del contenido?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solución!**, Crear componente Heredado del GridView, con nombre MyGridView

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class MyGridView extends GridView {

    public MyGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyGridView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2,
                MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);
    }
}
```

Su uso, atención en poner bien la ruta del package nombrepackage.MyGridView

```
<com.youpackage.app.MyGridView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
```

Y si se quiere quitar el efecto que parezca que se puede clickear

```
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 3):

**1-Primero**
Deberías ver opciones mas actuales y mas eficiente en lo que a memoria se refiere, me refiero al `RecyclerView` y al [GridLayoutManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html)

**2-segundo** Si necesitas usar un `GridView` y ademas si o si tiene que estar dentro un `ScrollView` eso solo haciendo un `Custom GridView` puedes ver este [enlace](http://www.londatiga.net/it/programming/android/make-android-listview-gridview-expandable-inside-scrollview/) que por lo que he visto de cualquier modo crea fugas de memoria.

**3-tercero** tan simple usar el Scroll que viene en el GridView ejemplo.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnWidth="120dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp" />
```

**4- por decir algo** no es muy bonito.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
 <ScrollView 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <TuLayoutDetalles>//info</TuLayoutDetalles>
</ScrollView>
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnWidth="120dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp" />
```

PD: los `namespace` siempre van en el  `Layout` padre.

Comment: Los layouts tipo "detalle" que engloban diferentes objetos y que no caben en una sola pagina, no hay alguna solución, o siempre se debe crear interficies fijas?

Comment: he actualizado la respuesta 4 punto.

Comment: ostias fue el copy paste que me jugo una mala pasada, lo de scrollview antes de la toolbar *facepalm*

Comment: acepta mi respuesta entonces :)

Comment: reabro pregunta ya que me sigue mostrandose 1 fila en el gridview, he encontrado algo como crear un gridview expandable heredado de gridview, creo que puede ser una solución

Comment: Si era el segundo punto que tenia un enlace a un Custom  Gridview

Answer (score 1):

Yo hice un método en su momento para esto que me ha venido muy bien, ya que me ahorró hacer clases personalizadas, importar librerías de terceros, etc, etc:

Para un list:

```
 public void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {

        // Calculamos caunto hay que desplegar el GridView para poder mostrarlo todo dentro del ScrollView

        try{

            int alturaTotal = 0;
            int items = myListAdapter.getCount();
            int filas = 0;

            View listItem = myListAdapter.getView(0, null, listView);
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            alturaTotal = listItem.getMeasuredHeight();

            float x = 1;

            x = items;
            filas = (int) (x + 2);
            alturaTotal *= filas;

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = alturaTotal;
            listView.setLayoutParams(params);

        }
        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){}
    }
```

Para un grid:

```
  public void setGridViewHeightBasedOnChildren(GridView gridView, int columnas) {

        // Calculamos caunto hay que desplegar el GridView para poder mostrarlo todo dentro del ScrollView

        try {

            int alturaTotal = 0;
            int items = myGridAdapter.getCount();
            int filas = 0;

            View listItem = myGridAdapter.getView(0, null, gridView);
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            alturaTotal = listItem.getMeasuredHeight();

            float x = 1;

            if (items > columnas) {
                x = items / columnas;
                filas = (int) (x + 1);
                alturaTotal *= filas;
            }

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = gridView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = alturaTotal;
            gridView.setLayoutParams(params);

        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){}
    }
```

Ese es el método y finalmente una vez que has cargado tu listView llamas al método de esta manera:

```
setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listCanciones);
```